# recursive methode for a micro-Syntax analyzer

Tags: algorithm, recursion, syntax, compiler-construction, analyzer

### here are the rules

`<nonterminal>
a/b := a or b`

---

ok lets start :

```
<Noun>::= *** // i manged to figure this out
<Constant>::= *** // i manged to figure this out    
<operator>::= "+"/"-"/"*"    // i manged to figure this out
```

the problem now is here

```
<Expression>::= <Expression><operator><Expression> / (<Expression>) / <Noun> / <Constant>
```

my attempt was like this

result Object is an object that holds two attributes

boolean t : returns if a statement is true or false

int pos : returns the position of where we should continue reading through the Tokens Array

```
private result Exp (int in){
    result x=new result(false,0);
    if(nom(in).t){x.t=true; x.pos=in+1;} else
    if(Constante(in).t){x.t=true; x.pos=Constante(in).pos+1;} else
    if(mot(in).equals("(")){x.t=(Exp(in+1).t&&mot(Exp(in+1).pos).equals(")"));
    x.pos=Exp(in+1).pos+1;} else
    {x.t=Exp(in).t&&
            Operateur(Exp(in).pos).t &&
            Exp(Operateur(Exp(in).pos).pos).t;
    x.pos=Exp(Operateur(Exp(in).pos).pos).pos+1;}

    return x;
}
```

the results for the following test were

jack = true  (correct)

25 = true (correct)

(jack) = true  (correct)

(jack( = false  (correct)

((jack) = false  (correct)

((jack)) = true  (correct)

But when it comes to testing an expression with an operator it returns always false

(jack + sami) = false (NOT correct , its supposed to be true)

Answer (score 0):

currently it fails because of the order of implementation..
your rule

```
<Expression>::= <Expression><operator><Expression> / (<Expression>) / <Noun> / <Constant>
```

is implemented as

```
<Expression>::= <Noun> / <Constant> / (<Expression>) / <Expression><operator><Expression>
```

wich means as soon as the function encounter a noun it returns;
so the match goes like this

```
token 1 "(" == <Noun>//false goto next

token 1 "(" == <Constant>//false goto next

token 1 "(" == "("//yes parse token 2 as sub expression
    token 2 "jack" == <Noun>//yes return true
token 3 "+" == ")"//no parent sub expression failed.. return false
```

to fix this specific example you shoud change the order of the ifs to something at least like

```
<Expression>::= <Expression><operator><Expression> / <Noun> / <Constant> / (<Expression>)
```

but the real problem comes from your grammar.. it should be something like

```
<Expression>::= <Primitive> / <Primitive><operator><Primitive>
<Primitive>::= <Noun> / <Constant> / (<Expression>)
```

Comment: thnx man , i eleminated left recursion , its the correct move